# SCRIPT tag removed from AJAX response in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, innerhtml, script-tag

In our current project some code is returned with AJAX and we use innerHTML to place this code inside a DIV.

Now we search this DIV for all available script tags and EVAL() the contents of these script tags (adds some information to a global array, etc)

```
scriptTags = responseElement.getElementsByTagName("script");

for (i = 0; i < scriptTags.length; i++) {
            eval(scriptTags[i].text);
        }
```

This works perfect in Firefox and Chrome. But in IE scriptTags appears to be empty. Upon further investigation it seems that the innerHTML of the responseElement doesn't contain any SCRIPT tags (while in Firefox / Chrome they're there!)

Anyone know the cause and/or work around?

By the way, this is how I put the AJAX response on the page:

```
this.proxy.innerHTML = o.responseText;
scriptTags = this.proxy.getElementsByTagName("script");
```

Debugging o.responseText shows the SCRIPT tags inside the response. Navigating to this.proxy element on the page shows **no** SCRIPT tag in IE but does show up in Firefox / Chrome.

Comment: Currently only testing in IE8 - where this behavior / issue occurs. So assume it's also an issue in IE7. IE9 should play nice, I hope. But currently working on Ubuntu only so no real testing environment available for IE.

Comment: Check this [article](http://allofetechnical.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/ies-innerhtml-method-with-script-and-style-tags/)

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897(v=vs.85).aspx) at M$ about `innerHTML` says you have to put "DEFER" attribute to your scripts. Check also this other [article](http://poeticcode.wordpress.com/2007/10/03/innerhtml-and-script-tags/).

Comment: I found those as well but didn't really solve our problem. However I came across another source: http://allofetechnical.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/ies-innerhtml-method-with-script-and-style-tags/ and it seems that the solution and cause offered there is applicable to our condition. Our first child node is the script tag. Rendering something in front of it suddenly makes it work correctly in IE.

Comment: 'eval' of remotely fetched content is probably a bad idea. (I'm not saying it's causing this problem, it's just unwise generally.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed by adding an additional node element before the SCRIPT tags that were in de AJAX response. (solution/cause: http://allofetechnical.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/ies-innerhtml-method-with-script-and-style-tags/)

In the future we should change our application so that the HTML is sent back as JSON.

Comment: +1 I was encountering this issue too, I'll now check with this approach :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link to the post, for me the 'defer' attribute worked.