# RegisterClientScriptBlock within an Update Panel PostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, registerstartupscript

*ASP.NET VB PostBack within an Update Panel*

I'm trying to have a JS function load on this error (closes Loading overlay & pop-up w/ error should come up).  When I try to display the label it works without a problem (of course it's covered by the overlay).

```
Me.lblerrormsg.Visible = True
```

I've tried 3 different approaches I've found for Registering a Script:

```
Dim errorScript = "<script>alert('WTF');</script>" '<-- not even this works

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "errorDemoManual",
     errorScript, True)

'Tried this one with the Panel & Page itself...
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(pnlPatientInfo, pnlPatientInfo.GetType(), 
     "ErrorDemo", errorScript, True)

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "errorScript",
     errorScript, True)
```

**None** have worked... Is there something I'm missing here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I needed to be using RadScriptManager - part of Telerik UpdatePanels to get it working.

```
RadScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "errorDemoManual", "errorDemoManual();", True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that any of those would work, as (I think, though I could be wrong) those methods only operate by adding the scripts to the beginning or the end of the html page *form*.  You *might* be able to render your script directly into the ajax response, say using a literal control within your update panel, but I recall having some issue with that. It's been a few years, but it seems to run along the lines of this question: [SCRIPT tag removed from AJAX response in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430141/script-tag-removed-from-ajax-response-in-internet-explorer). Note: they apparently solved their issue with some tweaking of the html sent as a response. A *somewhat* safe bet is to have some sort of hidden input or content in your update panel that has everything you need, and have some sort of javascript that only runs when the update panel is updated and have it fire off something based upon the hidden input or content.  Of course, that can easily become a pain in the ass to set up and maintain (unless, perhaps, you are using some sort of generic `event` mechanisms some javascript libraries provide).

Comment: Thanks for the help Jay! Looks like the issue was since I'm using Telerik UpdatePanels I needed to use : `RadScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`. Now everything works finally!